# Why would this parameter be ignored if provided in Python StreamReader?

Tags: python-3.x

In python, I am reading a file in order to process it.

My goal is to read X lines of that file at once, process the batch of lines and repeat until there is no line left to process in the file.

The StreamReader I am using is of type: `<class 'encodings.cp437.StreamReader'>`

It is the result of:

```
with hdfs.read("myfile", encoding="cp437") as reader:
```

where hdfs is `InsecureClient` from [there](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdfs.client.Client.read)

I found [this documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/codecs.StreamReader-class.html#readlines) about the `cp437` encoded `StreamReader` `readlines`.

The documentation says:

> sizehint, if given, is ignored since there is no efficient way to
> finding the true end-of-line.

- What does that actually means ? I do not understand why you would allow a parameter that will be ignored.
- What is it even supposed to do ?

Comment: your documentation link seems incorrect. https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.StreamReader.readlines

Comment: Indeed. Feel free to write an answer for that. I will accept it.

Comment: cool, ideally we could have closed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation it should work as expected, the documentation link you provided is incorrect.

Correct link:https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.StreamReader.readlines.

Quoting:

> readlines([sizehint[, keepends]])¶
>
> Read all lines
> available on the input stream and return them as a list of lines.
>
> Line-endings are implemented using the codec’s decode() method and are included in the
> list entries if *keepends* is true.
>
> *sizehint*,
> if given, is passed as the *size* argument to the stream’s read()
> method.